# PHP contact form error that i cant find

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

can someone help me with this?
I simply can't find the problem.
Mail just wont go.

HTML :

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<div class="span_of_2">
<div class="span2_of_1">
<h4>Name:</h4>
<div class="book_date btm">

<input class=""  type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">

</div>
<h4>Check in:</h4>
<div class="book_date btm">

<input name="checkin" class="date" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">

</div>  
<div class="sel_room">
<h4>Apartment:</h4>
<select id="country" onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field required" name="apartment">
<option value="null">Pick an apartment:</option>
<option value="1">Small apartment</option>         
<option value="2">Big apartment</option>
</select>
</div>  
<div class="sel_room left">
<h4>Adults:</h4>
<select id="country" onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field required" name="persons">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>         
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="span2_of_1">
<h4>e-mail</h4>
<div class="book_date btm">

<input class=""  type="text" placeholder="e-mail" name="email">

</div>
<h4>Check out:</h4>
<div class="book_date btm">

<input name="checkout" class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" value="DD/MM/YY" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'DD/MM/YY';}">

</div>      
<div class="sel_room">
<h4>Children:</h4>
<select id="country" onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field required" name="kids">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>         
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</div>  

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="res_btn" style="margin:0 auto;">

<input type="submit" value="Make reservation" style="background: #32A2E3; height: 50px; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;" name="send">

</div>
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["send"])){

$Name = $_POST["name"];
$Email = $_POST["email"];
$Checkout = $_POST["checkout"];
$Checkin = $_POST["checkin"];
$Apartment = $_POST["apartment"];
$Persons = $_POST["persons"];
$Kids = $_POST["kids"];

$To = "jurica.mlinaric@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$Subject = "Apartmani Costa Rica";
$Message = "From : $Name"; 
$Headers = $Email;
mail($To, $Subject, $Message);
echo "Email Sent.";

}

?>
```

I really dont know what the problem is. Its a simple html contact form. My server is but it just wont send it.

Comment: Do you have a mail server or mail transfer agent installed?

Comment: I think that the server should have that covered.

Comment: Do you get `Email Sent` outputted?

Comment: Ok, then whats in your mail log ? Maybe some clues in there

Comment: no, just the The page cannot be displayed error message

Comment: Can you rephrase that? The PHP page the form submits to isn't loading?

Comment: yes, like it isnt there

Comment: post the *exact* error message. Would of helped if you had done that in the fist place :-)

Comment: The page cannot be displayed

The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
Please try the following:

Contact the Web site administrator if you believe that this request should be allowed.
Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly.
HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Technical Information (for support personnel)

.....

Comment: Hmm never seen that error before, but maybe `method="POST"`, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828726, `The HTTP specifications also state that HTTP verbs are case-sensitive.`. Is this the only page you have this behavior on?

Comment: yes, and its not POST, change it to lower case and still not sending

Comment: Sounds like an IIS server configuration issue, not PHP. Might want to try on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: The HTTP request probably has an `Allow:` header. Open your console, go to "Network" tab and then look at the headers there. The `POST` method is most likely not there, which means that the server needs to be configured to allow it.

Answer (score -2):

Replace this section:

```
$Headers = $Email;
mail($To, $Subject, $Message);
```

With this:

```
$Headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$Headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$Headers .= "From: ". $Name;
mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);
```

Comment: did it, still not sending

Comment: not a surprise when the file with the php is never actually run